# Connecting BeagleBone through crossover cable?

Tags: linux, windows, ip, lan, beagleboard

I made a crossover cable to connect my laptop to my BeagleBone without router. The problem is without router my BB doesnt have IP address so I can't ping it. How do I configure my BB and my laptop to assign a static IP connection between my BB (running [latest debian image](http://beagleboard.org/latest-images)) and my laptop (running Windows 8.1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You setup a static address inside the BB. Then it can be addressed just as in a normal network. You just have to make sure that the routine ruleset on your notebook known which network interface to use to reach the BB.

So typically the BB gets a static address in a a separate local network. Same for the notebook, you configure a static address inside that separate network for the network interface you use to connect to the BB. That way the system known what packages to send and receive via which network adapter.

Comment: Thank you I can ssh to it now, but still the BB doesn't have internet connection. How can I share my laptop Wi-Fi with my BB? I already set the Wi-Fi setting on Windows to share to Ethernet, but my BB is still not connected to the internet. Or should I make new question?

Comment: Most likely that is cause by a missing routing entry on the BB. It has to know where to send packages "to the internet". I have no idea about MS-Windows and how to use it's networking stack for such purpose. So it probably makes sense to post a separate question where you include the exact network configuration on the BB and on your notebook.

Comment: Thank u I'll post a new question then.